# BigQuery SQL 'NOT IN' not excluding results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to filter out some records from a BigQuery query using `WHERE NOT IN`, however, I am getting the same number of results with or without this code and my required exclusions are still being included.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    EmailHash,
    DATE(MAX(OrderDate)) AS max_ord_date
    FROM `project.dataset.Header`
    WHERE Date(OrderDate) = '2019-05-15'
    # AND mb_company = 'CORE'
    AND CancelledFlag IS NOT True
    AND AmountPaid > 0
    # Exclude these order numbers
    AND ordernumber NOT IN (
        SELECT ordernumber FROM(
            SELECT 
            ordernumber,
            SUM(SAFE_CAST(StockOutQuantity AS INT64)) AS so,
            SUM(QuantityCancelled) AS cx,
            SUM(Quantity) AS ord
            FROM `project.dataset.Detail`
            WHERE Date(OrderDate) = '2019-05-15'
            GROUP BY ordernumber
            HAVING so = ord)
            )
    # Exclude these order numbers
    AND ordernumber NOT IN (
        SELECT ordernumber FROM(
            SELECT 
            ordernumber,
            SUM(AmountPaid) ap,
            ROUND(SUM(AmountPaid) - (SUM(PnPOrder) + SUM(PnPOrderTax)),2) ap_ntx,
            SUM(RefundedValue) rv,
            SUM(GoodsNet) gn
            FROM `project.dataset.Header`
            WHERE Date(OrderDate) = '2019-05-15'
            GROUP BY ordernumber
            HAVING (ap = rv) OR (ap_ntx = rv) OR (gn = rv)
            )
    )
    GROUP BY EmailHash
```

Running this query returns 10802 results.

When I run the SQL below I see 17 orders which should be excluded from the total results.

```
SELECT ordernumber FROM(
                SELECT 
                ordernumber,
                SUM(SAFE_CAST(StockOutQuantity AS INT64)) AS so,
                SUM(QuantityCancelled) AS cx,
                SUM(Quantity) AS ord
                FROM `project.dataset.Detail`
                WHERE Date(OrderDate) = '2019-05-15'
                GROUP BY ordernumber
                HAVING so = ord)
```

My second NO clause should remove a further 293 orders from the total, but these order numbers are still present. If I comment out these two WHERE clauses I get the same number of results back, so clearly the orders they return are not being excluded, what am I missing in my code to exclude these records?

Comment: You are combining `NOT IN` clauses with `AND`. This means, only records which are in neither of the subqueries are excluded. IE an ordernumber which is contained in one of the subqueries is included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Could be you are looking for the NOT IN the UNION Between the querues for ordernumber

```
SELECT 
    EmailHash,
    DATE(MAX(OrderDate)) AS max_ord_date
    FROM `project.dataset.Header`
    WHERE Date(OrderDate) = '2019-05-15'
    # AND mb_company = 'CORE'
    AND CancelledFlag IS NOT True
    AND AmountPaid > 0
    # Exclude these order numbers
    AND ordernumber NOT IN (
        SELECT ordernumber FROM(
            SELECT 
            ordernumber,
            SUM(SAFE_CAST(StockOutQuantity AS INT64)) AS so,
            SUM(QuantityCancelled) AS cx,
            SUM(Quantity) AS ord
            FROM `project.dataset.Detail`
            WHERE Date(OrderDate) = '2019-05-15'
            GROUP BY ordernumber
            HAVING so = ord)
        UNION 
        SELECT ordernumber FROM(
            SELECT 
            ordernumber,
            SUM(AmountPaid) ap,
            ROUND(SUM(AmountPaid) - (SUM(PnPOrder) + SUM(PnPOrderTax)),2) ap_ntx,
            SUM(RefundedValue) rv,
            SUM(GoodsNet) gn
            FROM `project.dataset.Header`
            WHERE Date(OrderDate) = '2019-05-15'
            GROUP BY ordernumber
            HAVING (ap = rv) OR (ap_ntx = rv) OR (gn = rv)
            )
    )
    GROUP BY EmailHash
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is still returning 10802 rows.

Comment: then udpate your question and   a proper data sample the actual result and the expcted  result

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the correct order numbers are being selected in the union, but they continue to be present in the results, not excluded.

Comment: which data type is ordernumber ??

Comment: It's an integer.

Comment: please  if you can show a simple data sample  .. seem strange to me that a NOT IN don't work ..